# blackberry 10 javascript get device phone number

Tags: javascript, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-10

I am trying to get the phone number from javascript. I saw several code samples but were all for pre BB10. I have also tried this code and

```
var lines = blackberry.identity.phone.getLineNumber(1);

for (var i = 0; i < lines.length - 1; i++) {
    alert(blackberry.identity.phone.getLineNumber(lines[i]));
}
```

But it returned undefined. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this going to be an app calling for code on your server or a browser-based site?

Comment: this is going to be a webworks app that will be running on the device

Comment: On BlackBerry 10, the blackberry.identity object contains the IMEI, IMSI and uuid (PIN). The documentation shows that feature id="blackberry.identity.phone" applies to BlackBerry 10, but it does not, I will see that the docs are updated.
FYI, you can use Web Inspector's console tab to see what is inside the blackberry object and it's contents. Just type blackberry.identity and hit enter, then navigate through the object. More info here: [link](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/web_inspector_overview_1553586_11.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var lines = blackberry.identity.phone.getLineIds();
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length-1; i++) {
    alert("Line id : " + lines[i] + " has phone number : " + blackberry.identity.phone.getLineNumber(lines[i]));
  }
</script>
```

Source: Your best friend, the [API Reference](http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.identity.phone.html)

Comment: I tried that one. First place I started and I get the following error when using it "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getLineIds' of undefined "

Comment: Hmm have you tried printing the result of blackberry.identity.phone.getLineIds()?

Comment: verified that phone is not part of indentity

    Object {event: Object, app: Object, identity: Object, system:     Object, connection: Object…}
    app: Object
    connection: Object
    event: Object
    identity: Object
    get IMEI: function (){return    deviceSettings.retrieve("identity.IMEI")}
    get uuid: function (){return   deviceSettings.retrieve("identity.uuid")}
    set IMEI: undefined
    set uuid: undefined
    __proto__: Object
    system: Object
    ui: Object
    __proto__: Object

Comment: But that might be correct. getLineIds is just a method inside the identity object, so it might be calling the number from somewhere else. You could try doing var lines = blackberry.identity.phone.getLineIds();  and printing the content of lines;

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getLineIds' of undefined "

Comment: Look at this link http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.identity.html   and the Supported Platform Table   BB10 doesn't allow getLineIds() but may be with a permission? Some apps on OS went through the hassle of asking users for their phones (and verifying them with a sms) after Apple determinately forbid getting the phone number through the API.

Comment: blackberry.identity.phone is not supported on BlackBerry 10.  That API was for the older (java-based) BlackBerry 5/6/7 platforms.